# Is this code from old Alexandrescu's C++ book valid?

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading the old Alexandrescu's book about C++ templates and came across the following code snippet where he explained AbstractFactory pattern implementation (Chapter 9.3). Here it is:

```
template <class, class, class> class GenLinearHierachy;
template <class, class> class OPNewFactoryUnit;
template <class> class Reverse;

//definitions

template
<
    class AbstractFact,
    template <class, class> class Creator = OPNewFactoryUnit
    class TList = typename AbstractFact::ProductList
>
class ConcreteFactory
: public GenLinearHierarchy<
typename TL::Reverse<TList>::Result, Creator, AbstractFact> //HERE.
{
public:
    typedef typename AbstractFact::ProductList ProductList;
    typedef TList ConcreteProductList;
};
```

I don't get why the code is valid. We didn't defined `TL` anywhere in the snippet.

Comment: Imagine if all questions on this site had titles like yours :)

Comment: Did you try compiling the code? There's typos in it.

Comment: The code in question appears to also have `#include "Typelist.h"`, which defines `namespace TL`.  [(reference)](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00644.html)

Comment: I did not see anyone comment on calling the book "old". Have there been any development as far as the designs are concerned since then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the code you've posted is not correct.

There's a few typos which probably aren't very relevant but I'll mention them. They may be in the book or maybe they were made by yourself when you posted this. I don't have the book so I can't check

- `GenLinearHierachy` should probably be `GenLinearHierarchy`
- Comma missing at the end of `OPNewFactoryUnit` before another template parameter

Now that those are out of the way, no the snippet does not declare `TL` namespace or `template <class> class Reverse;` inside that namespace. It does declare `template <class> class Reverse;` outside `TL` namespace, so it might be an error in the book assuming that's the entire snippet and there's no reason to assume that additional headers would be required.

The declaration is probably related to `Loki::TL::Reverse< NullType >` which is declared in [Typelist.h](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00681.html) of Loki library.

Third thing that I find confusing is that the template parameter `template <class, class> class Creator = OPNewFactoryUnit` is passed as a second type parameter to `template <class, class, class> class GenLinearHierachy` even though `Creator` is not a type but a template! Seems like `GenLinearHierarchy` would be intended to be `template <class, template <class, class> class, class> class GenLinearHierarchy;`. That would match with [LOKI::GenLinearHierarchy](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00653.html)

With those changes (fix typos, remove `TL` namespace, change type of `GenLinearHierarchy`), the code parses correctly.